# how to handle format of the Data in a UDP data Transfer

Tags: java, c#, udp

I am making a prototype MMORPG game, and I have read that it's best to use UDP to transfer player movements. So I have to transfer X,Y of the player right? so how do I manage the packet dropping (if any) of the connection.

Can someone explain me the way this UDP works, that how can I manage the format of the data that I transfer. If any of the packets drop that will cause the format to be useless right?

Comment: A google search would do much better!

Comment: i did , but I don't understand that how to make a format that doesn't get interrupted by dropping of packets :(

Comment: UDP transfer means, you are going to ignore package that are lost or there is no end point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP is connectionless. Each datagram is handled individually in isolation, and a datagram can be lost only as a whole unit or not at all.

So the solution to your concern is to make sure a single datagram contains all of the information needed.

For example, assuming that at a minimum you need to send a player ID along with an X and a Y coordinate, you could send three `int` values.

There are lots of ways to build the datagram itself (which is sent as a `byte[]`), but one of the simplest is to use `BinaryWriter`:

```
byte[] BuildDatagram(int playerId, int x, int y)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream)
    using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.Write(playerId);
        writer.Write(x);
        writer.Write(y);
        writer.Flush();
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Note that the reason that UDP is reasonable to use for player position is that if you lose the occasional datagram, it's not a big problem. Similarly, receiving the same datagram multiple times is usually not a big problem. And finally, receiving the datagrams in a different order than in which they were sent is not *too* much of a problem (though players will find that the most annoying of the three possible problems UDP could cause).

You would only want to use UDP for this kind of data. Anything you want to be sent reliably, you'll either need to add code to your UDP implementation to ensure reliability (which is fairly complicated, especially for someone unfamiliar with network programming in general), or you'll want to use TCP for those kinds of data.

Comment: Thank You, this is the answer that I was Searching for :D